# How to handle String mechanism in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a small piece of code inside the return. for example

```
const Demo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            props.map((val, index) => (
                <h2>{val.fileName}</h2>
            ))
        </div>
    )  
}
```

The output is coming like this:
`F:\test\form\student.html`
But inside I don't want this type of output. I want to modify the output like: `F:\test\form\form.pdf`

1. The last student.html will remove and the form must become 2 times will repeat and lastly, the extension is pdf

   ```
    original output: F:\test\form\student.html
    desired output: F:\test\form\form.pdf
   ```

can you help how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help as per my understanding of your question

```
const Demo = (props) => {
    const processedFileNames = props.map((val, index) = {
        const splitFileName = val.fileName.split('\\');
        splitFileName[splitFileName.length - 1] = splitFileName[splitFileName.length - 2];
        return splitFileName.join('\\') + '.pdf';
    })
    return (
        <div>
            processedFileNames.map((val, index) => (
                <h2>{val}</h2>
            ))
        </div>
    )
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: We use the map. so every time we can't get the student.html and form. sometimes also we get some other Html and instead of form, we will get some other things. I hope u understand my point. we need dynamic

Comment: @RajendraBar can you please explain your question with more variations.

Comment: actually i am using map. so when i print `{val.pathName}` i got the output like
 ```F:\test\book1\student.html
 F:\test\book2\dolor.html
 F:\test\book3\elit.html
 F:\test\book4\amet.html```


But my desired output is:  
 ```F:\test\book1\student.html ----> F:\test\book1\book1.pdf
 F:\test\book2\dolor.html  ----> F:\test\book2\book2.pdf
 F:\test\book3\elit.html  ----> F:\test\book3\book3.pdf
 F:\test\book4\amet.html  ----> F:\test\book4\book4.pdf```
plz look the book1/ book2/ book3 are repeat 2 times.

Comment: Hi @RajendraBar, I changed the code. please check and let me know you need any more help.